# Sphinx searchd dead but subsys locked

Tags: centos6, sphinxsearch, sphinx

I have configured everything on sphinx. It is working fine in the command-line interface using Putty. Even i can able to search in the Command Line Interface as below,

```
[root@phpsalzer sphinx]# search -i gplay 'toy'
Sphinx 2.0.4-id64-release (r3135)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf'...
index 'gplay': query 'toy ': returned 1 matches of 1 total in 0.000 sec

displaying matches:
1. document=2, weight=1883, app_id=com.disney.ToyStorySmashIt.goo, app_title=Toy Story: Smash It!, app_ratings=4.500000

words:
1. 'toy': 1 documents, 4 hits
```

But the issues is, i want to get the same result using php. But it returns the error like "`ERROR: Query failed: connection to 172.16.1.77:9312 failed (errno=13, msg=Permission denied).` "

Finally, It Seems that my sphinx port is not in LISTEN after checking the below commands,

```
service searchd status
```

The output is: `searchd dead but subsys locked`

```
netstat -tulpen | grep :9312
```

The output is nothing.

Please help me, what should i do next?

Comment: Does searchd have a log in /var/logs?

Comment: No. It doesn't have log files /var/logs

Answer (score 3):

Try removing binlog files first and then start searchd

```
rm -f /var/lib/sphinx/binlog.*
```

As suggested by Adalbert  on http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=7445

Answer (score 0):

Try this on sphinx conf:

binlog_path = #

Then service searchd restart and service searchd status.